# Invalid function name "," in ksh

Tags: bash, ksh

This is my system:

```
# cat /etc/*release*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

and I run `ksh`.

I have, for a long time, had a function in my profile, defined like this:

```
function ,
{
  sudo bash --init-file ~/.bashrc
}
```

This has worked in the past, but now I get `/etc/profile: line 78: ,: invalid function name` when I log in. Is this something new, or is it only allowed in `bash`? This is not really critical, but I like the terseness of that name.